# Scraping information from multiple webpages using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape the results from the 2012-2016 Stockholm Marathon races. I am able to do so using the code outlined below, but every time that I've scraped the results from one year I have to go through the process of manually changing the URL to capture the next year.

This bothers me as the only thing that needs to change is the **bold** part of http://results.marathon.se/**2012**/?content=list&event=STHM&num_results=250&page=1&pid=list&search[sex]=M&lang=SE.

How can I modify the code below so that it scrapes the results from each year, outputting the results into a single dataframe that also includes a column to indicate the year to which the observation belongs?

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# Find the total number of pages to scrape
tot_pages <- read_html('http://results.marathon.se/2012/?content=list&event=STHM&num_results=250&page=1&pid=list&search[sex]=M&lang=EN') %>%
  html_nodes('a:nth-child(6)') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()

#Store the URLs in a vector
URLs <- sprintf('http://results.marathon.se/2012/?content=list&event=STHM&num_results=250&page=%s&pid=list&search[sex]=M&lang=EN', 1:tot_pages)

#Create a progress bar
pb <- progress_estimated(tot_pages, min = 0)

# Create a function to scrape the name and finishing time from each page
getdata <- function(URL) {
  pb$tick()$print()
  pg <- read_html(URL)
  html_nodes(pg, 'tbody td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text() %>% as_tibble() %>% set_names(c('Name')) %>%
mutate(finish_time = html_nodes(pg, 'tbody .right') %>% html_text())
}

#Map everything into a dataframe
map_df(URLs, getdata) -> results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# make a vector of the years you want
years <- seq(2012,2016)

# now use lapply to iterate your code over those years
Results.list <- lapply(years, function(x) {

  # make a target url with the relevant year
  link <- sprintf('http://results.marathon.se/%s/?content=list&event=STHM&num_results=250&page=1&pid=list&search[sex]=M&lang=EN', x)

  # Find the total number of pages to scrape
  tot_pages <- read_html(link) %>%
    html_nodes('a:nth-child(6)') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()

  # Store the URLs in a vector
  URLs <- sprintf('http://results.marathon.se/%s/?content=list&event=STHM&num_results=250&page=%s&pid=list&search[sex]=M&lang=EN', x, 1:tot_pages)

  #Create a progress bar
  pb <- progress_estimated(tot_pages, min = 0)

  # Create a function to scrape the name and finishing time from each page
  getdata <- function(URL) {
    pb$tick()$print()
    pg <- read_html(URL)
    html_nodes(pg, 'tbody td:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text() %>% as_tibble() %>% set_names(c('Name')) %>%
    mutate(finish_time = html_nodes(pg, 'tbody .right') %>% html_text())
  }

  #Map everything into a dataframe
  map_df(URLs, getdata) -> results

  # add an id column indicating which year
  results$year <- x

  return(results)

})

# now collapse the resulting list into one tidy df
Results <- bind_rows(Results.list)
```